# Images not loading but path is correct

Tags: reactjs, elixir, phoenix-framework

Below is my file structure right now.

I am in the file Move.jsx and I have this line of code:

```
<img src="../images/attack.png" />
```

Running this locally, I believe this should work and display an image but when the page loads there is no image being displayed instead the broken image symbol is displayed. 
[image]

The chrome console output has this error

```
GET http://localhost:4000/images/attack.png 404 (Not Found)
```

[image]

Comment: You are showing us the directory structure of your source files, not of the generated package. The important thing is what is inside `_build` folder.

Comment: @Sulthan I've never looked into the `_build` folder. Could you give me some pointers as to what to do there?

Comment: That `..` is executed relative to the base URL. The server doesn't know about folders. You can see that the final URL is `http://localhost:4000/images/attack.png`, which probably means `_build/images/attack.png`. You should make sure you are copying assets correctly to build.

Comment: You should have something like Webpack that packages all your files. You can actually use Webpack to load images by using the ES6 import syntax or have Webpack / Gulp dump your images to an `img` folder inside your `build` folder as mentioned by @Sulthan

Comment: @Sulthan I was not aware I had to copy the images into the _build folder. I didn't know I was supposed to touch the _build folder. Is this how it is normally done?

Comment: @isignisign You are not supposed to touch it manually, that's why we have build systems. However, you should understand what's inside and how it is generated.

Comment: @Sulthan I don't have an images folder in the `_build` folder. Shouldn't it be put together when I run `mix phx.server`?

Comment: I don't really know `phonix` so I can't really help you with the setup. I believe the problem is with the URL, the images are definitely copied somewhere else.

Comment: Your url should be fine when you use the brunch defaults, it usually copies the static files from `assets/static` (`.../images` etc), in your case you have those files in `assets/images` so unless you make your loader copy them from the correct location it won't work. So you need to either change brunch-config `conventions` key or webpack.config

Answer (score 2):

You are going to want to use the `static_path/2` helper function. You should be able to use

```
<img src="<$= static_path(@conn, "/images/attack.png") %>" />
```

You can take a look at `templates/layout/app.html.eex`, it should have something similar for your css and javascript files.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I had to manually copy my images from /static/images to /priv/static/images for some reason it wasn't automatically copying it over for me.

Thanks for all the help everyone!